# Why is static int always 0 when accessed from another class

Tags: c#, static, int

I have a class with a static `int`. I want that `int`, once set, to be accessible anywhere in my program.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static int myInt;
   public MyClass()
   {
      myInt = 100;
      new TestClass();
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      new MyClass();
   }
}
```

..but when I try to call it in another class

```
public class TestClass
{
   public TestClass()
   {
      int testInt = MyClass.myInt;
   }
}
```

..`testInt` is always 0, even when I check in debug mode and see that the static int was successfully set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually the posted code does work, as `MyClass` instance constructor is called in `static void Main(string[] args)`; and the `TestClass` constructor is called after `myInt` has been assigned the value of `100`...So `testInt` cannot be `0` in the above code, it is definitely `100`...The problem is hidden probably in the way the OP checked that it was `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You never instantiate an instance of the class... so the constructor never gets fired.

What you want is a *static constructor*.. to initialize static members:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static int myInt;

    static MyClass() { // Static Constructor
        myInt = 100;
    }
}
```

A `static` constructor is guaranteed to be fired before any access to an object. Exactly when is undetermined.

Comment: @GrantWinney He didn't say it was hit by a breakpoint, he probably just checked the variable's value while in the debugger and saw that it was 0.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead, he does instantiate an instance of `MyClass`

Answer (score 2):

Well either as @Simon Whitehead suggested or the best way for this kind of thing is to initialize it when declaring. So you can write it like this:

```
public static int myInt = 100;
```

as this is not dependent on anything else, you don't need to wait for constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any problem in the OP, as the code indeed does the expected job:

[image]

Try adding `Console.WriteLine(testInt);` in the end of the `TestClass` constructor. If the code equals the one posted, it should output `100`.